# Кроме как в 13-м часу(,)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вставная-конструкция

Как правильно? Я думаю, что вариант 2-й правильный, а 1-й — ложный.

1. Когда ты завтра – можешь приехать когда хочешь, кроме как в 13-м часу – приедешь и сколько ты денег отдашь?
2. Когда ты завтра – можешь приехать когда хочешь, кроме как в 13-м часу, – приедешь и сколько ты денег отдашь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если разбирать только пунктуацию, то предложение надо оформить по второму варианту:

*Когда ты завтра — можешь приехать когда хочешь, кроме как в 13-м часу, — приедешь и сколько ты денег отдашь?*

Сочетание [кроме как](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5) используется здесь в качестве ограничительного союза, поэтому после "часу" **нужна** запятая, закрывающая оборот.
"Когда захочешь" имеет в этом предложении значение "в любое время".

Смысл воспринимается не сразу, приходится разбираться, что к чему относится: "когда ты завтра можешь приехать" и "когда ты завтра приедешь".
Я бы написала так:
*Когда ты завтра приедешь — приезжай когда хочешь, кроме как в 13-м часу, — и сколько ты денег отдашь?*

[Вставные предложения и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125)

P. S. Из текста вопроса: *Я думаю, что вар. 2 прав, а 1-й – ложн.*
Вариант не может быть прав.
Обычно если в одном прилагательном используется наращение, то и в другом тоже.

Comment: В первом я сначала я пишу слово *вариант*, а потом – цифру, так что не ставлю наращение. Во втором я слово *вариант* пропускаю, так что наращение нужно. Правильно?