# Вариант 2 / вариант 2-й

Tags: наращение

Правда, что, если я хочу, чтобы читали в таком случае *вариант два*, наращение не надо ставить – то есть надо писать *вариант 2*, – а если хочу, чтобы сказали *вариант второй*, то надо писать *вариант 2-й*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• Вопрос, думаю, возник вот отсюда: «[Кроме как в 13-м часу(,)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475319/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-13-%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%83)».

В тексте заданного вопроса (до правки):
*Как правильно? Я думаю, что вар. 2 прав, а 1-й – ложн.*
(Мною сделана правка: *Я думаю, что вариант 2-й правильный, а 1-й — ложный.*)

• Мой **P. S.** в ответе:

> Вариант не может быть прав.
> Обычно если в одном прилагательном используется наращение, то и в другом тоже.

• Комментарий автора:
В первом я сначала я пишу слово *вариант*, а потом – цифру, так что не ставлю наращение. Во втором я слово *вариант* пропускаю, так что наращение нужно. Правильно?

**Разъяснение**
Если вы хотели написать "вариант два правильный", то после слова "прав" надо было поставить точку:
*Я думаю, что вар. 2 **прав.,** а 1-й – ложн.*

Мне кажется, что в тексте вопроса нет никакой необходимости таким образом сокращать слова — во избежание непоняток: что же у нас "прав", а что "ложн."?
Проще писать полностью — и будет всем понятно и удобно.

Comment: А если я хочу сказать *параграф второй*, то мне наращение нужно или нет, если я цифрой пишу?

Comment: В списках, в оглавлениях — § 2 (наращение не используется); в тексте — параграф 2-й, параграф второй.

Comment: То есть, если я говорю *вопрос второй*, я пишу *вопрос 2-й*; если я, однако, говорю *вопрос два*, я пишу *вопрос 2*. Так?

Comment: Так, Леопольд. Наращение собственно и дает читателю понять, какое числительное используется — количественное (два) или порядковое (второй).